# Windows 8 Layout on WPF using listbox or list view with data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm trying to custom my layout to be like windows 8 layout :

- Horizontal scroll
- 4 rows of elements (one Itemsource)

I'm binding RSS feed to my listbox , when i use a wrappanel i have problems with my DataTemplate .

i want also that the order of my element will be :

- 1 5 9  ...
- 2 6 10 ...
- 3 7 11 ...
- 4 8 12 ...
- [Scroll ]

My Xaml for the listbox :

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid Width="400" Height="100" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

i tried this but it doesn't work their is error on Listbox ItemTemplate :

```
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Width="400" Height="100" Cursor="Hand"  >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Perhaps a picture of what you want would be useful. I'm finding it difficult to imagine what you are after.

Comment: What problems with WrapPanel?

Comment: @MikeEason i cant post image on stackoverflow i'm new i haven't enough reputation i have tow pic i can't send them via mail

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov i added some code check my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to change WrapPanel Orientation to vertical

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

and move DataTemplate section out from ItemsPanel definition

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Width="400" Height="100" Cursor="Hand"  >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thanks @Vakera My data was displayed  , added ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" because i want a horizontalScroll .. but my Item are displayed is one row i want to costum this layout and have 4 rows

Comment: You need to set your ListBox height according to your wish.
So, it will be 100px * 4 rows = 400 px.
Don't forget for margins.